# Error mounting docker-compose volume for code-reloading

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple node script, and a Dockerfile and docker compose definition:

*app/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "puppeteer-scrape",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon scrape.js"
  }
}
```

*app/Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:8.11.3

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package* /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./*.js /app/

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: app
    volumes:
     - .:/app
```

I want to configure docker-compose to re-run the script when I change the application.

The [official docker-compose tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted) suggests the way to do this is with a volume definition as above.  However when I run `docker-compose up` I get:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
app_1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
app_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
app_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
app_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
app_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
app_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
app_1  | npm ERR! enoent 
app_1  | 
app_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-02T23_54_53_560Z-debug.log
```

It seems like the app directory is getting run-over, or `npm start` is being called before app is copied in.  What's the correct way to configure this?

Comment: Is your package.json located in the same directory of your docker-compose.yaml file?

Comment: @whites11 no, its in the app/sub-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a path mismatch:

- the command your container tries to run is `npm start` from the `app` directory (inside the container);
- `npm` wants the `package.json` file in the current directory, but with docker compose you're mounting it inside the app directory;
- as you mentioned, the `package.json` file is inside the app directory in your host, this means that it will be placed inside the `/app/app` directory in the running container.

Solution: either change the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile to `/app/app` or share the `app` local directory with this volume definition in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
- ./app:/app
```